# Updating progress bar for a long running method in Window form

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a MDI form in which, once I click on any menu item, the associated form is shown. Sometimes, forms take time to load, so I would like to show a progress bar for long-running calls.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.  What do you need help with and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Since few forms take time to open, you should be moving the form loading code into a separate thread using `background worker`(This will avoid UI from freezing). You can have `WorkerReportsProgress` property set to `true`, so that you can use it to show the progress in the progress bar in `ProgressChanged` event handler, while the loading.

If you do not have much idea about how to work with Background worker, I recommend you learn how to use them --- See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a VB.NET example, the essential part is to get the idea, so I would recommend this excellent article that answers your question:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58239-progress-bar-while-loading-a-child-form/

PS: It would not hurt to google it first.